# Bash : Can Here Strings <<< work with multiple variables as input?

Tags: arrays, bash, unix, sh

I am trying to initialize an array with multiple variables as below .

```
StringOne="This is a Test String"
StringTwo="This is a New String"
read -r -a Values <<< "$StringOne" "$StringTwo"
```

But It seems like array is getting values from only the first variable .ie StringOne

```
 $ echo ${Values[0]}
 This
 $ echo ${Values[1]}
 is
 $ echo ${Values[2]}
 a
 $ echo ${Values[3]}
 Test
 ${Values[4]}
 String
 $ echo ${Values[5]}

 $ echo ${Values[6]}

 $
```

What is wrong with this way of passing variable value for array initialization ? Cant we pass multiple variables with <<< operator ?

Comment: I want `${Values[5]}=This ${Values[6]}=is ${Values[7]}=a ${Values[8]}=New ` likewise

Comment: Does this solve your problem? `read -r -a Values <<< "$StringOne $StringTwo"`

Comment: thanks @gudok .this is working now

Comment: Aside: `declare -p Values` gives you an easier way to show the contents of an array.

Comment: ...what your original code was doing, by the way, was exactly equivalent to: `read -r -a Values "$StringTwo" <<<"$StringOne"`

Comment: Original command was `read -r -a Values <<< "$StringOne" "$StringTwo"` .And it was not taking the second varibale value in array . Now got the solution . Issue was with quoting .

Comment: Initializing an array like this is somewhat pointless. Arrays are meant to hold values that can't be represented in a flat string int he first place.

Comment: What is wrong with `Values=( $StringOne $StringTwo )`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with this way of passing variable value for array initialization ? Cant we pass multiple variables with <<< operator ?

Yes and no.  The `<<<` operator takes one shell word as its operand, as is presented pretty clearly in its documentation.  But you can combine the values of multiple variables in a single shell word by appropriate use of quoting:

```
StringOne="This is a Test String"
StringTwo="This is a New String"
read -r -a Values <<< "$StringOne $StringTwo"
echo "${Values[@]}"
```

Output:

> This is a Test String This is a New String

Comment: I didn't think about combining the output with quotes . Now I got it .

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
read -r -a Values <<< "$StringOne"" ""$StringTwo"
```

Or:

```
read -r -a Values <<< "$StringOne"' '"$StringTwo"
```

Or:

```
out="$StringOne $StringTwo"
read -r -a Values <<< "$out"
```

Or some other variation on this theme.

This works because the string sent via `<<<` is the result of the expansion of what in on the right of it. We can make both variables act as one long string by concatenating them.